# InvalidStackFrameException After Calling Method via ObjectReference#invokeMethod

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, scala-ide, jdi

I am currently working on an Eclipse plugin which enhances the debugging possibilities. During the debugging session, I invoke a Scala method via `com.sun.jdi.ObjectReference#invokeMethod` like that:

```
public int callMethod_Reactive_Level(final ObjectReference o) throws InvalidTypeException, ClassNotLoadedException, IncompatibleThreadStateException, InvocationException {
    final Method m = apiValues.getMethod_Reactive_level(o); // com.sun.jdi.Method
    final IntegerValue intVal = (IntegerValue) o.invokeMethod(thread, m, new LinkedList<Value>(), ObjectReference.INVOKE_SINGLE_THREADED);
    return intVal.intValue();
}
```

After doing that, a call to `org.eclipse.debug.core.model.IVariable#getValue` leads to an `InvalidStackFrameException`. The whole error message is:

```
Status ERROR: org.scala-ide.sdt.debug code=5010 Exception while retrieving variable's value com.sun.jdi.InvalidStackFrameException
```

The message `Exception while retrieving variable's value` is shown when I inspect a variable in the variables view after calling a method as shown above.

Any idea how this problem can be solved? I do not understand why this is so problematic, since the JDI explicitely provides the possibility to do that.

**Update:** Since it may be a bug in the Scala IDE, there is a discussion and a tutorial how to reproduce the issue in the [Scala IDE dev group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-ide-dev/xCKMltPVq7M).

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems to come from the Scala IDE implementation of `IVariable.getValue`. It delegates to the JDI `StackFrame.getValue`, which throws. According to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/jdi/), this can happen "if this stack frame has become invalid. Once the frame's thread is resumed, the stack frame is no longer valid."

My guess is that executing an `invokeMethod` on the same thread invalidates the stack frame.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how can I solve it? Can I inject a new thread into the VM and execute the method on this new thread?

Comment: It might be a bug in the Scala IDE (once the thread is stopped again after `invokeMethod`, it should refresh it's stack frame variables and propagate the change to the variable view). We could discuss on the [scala-ide-dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/scala-ide-dev) group.

Comment: I posted a topic in the group which still has to be approved (I think I posted it twice, sorry for that).